# Query for nested JSON property in azure CosmosDb

Tags: json, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I am having some difficulty crafting a query for nested data in cosmosDB.

Say I have data stored in this structure:

```
{
   id:"1234",
   data:{
       people:{
           "a826bbc5-add9-42d8-ba52-f5de52973556":{
               first_name: "Kyle"
           },
           "efb119d-9f12-4d11-a7e1-38e4719a699c":{
               first_name: "Bob"
           },
           "b402faac-d1ba-4317-9ba6-673c76a8fc37":{
               first_name: "Jane"
           }
       }
   }
}
```

Now I want to write a query that would return all of the people with the first name of "Bob"

I need something like:

```
Select * from c where c.data.people[*].first_name = "Bob";
```

Notice that the "people" object is an actual JSON object not a JSON array, so no array_contains, I need basically the JSON obj equivalent.

I've looked around and can't seem to find the appropriate query for this common use-case.

Anyone know how I can accomplish this query?

Comment: Are you saying you want to return each distinct `Bob` record from `people`? Or do you just need each record where `Bob` exists in `people`? For example, would you expect the record in your question to be returned or would you expect `{ "efb11...": "Bob" }` to be returned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the key of `people` objects is random,i'm afraid you can't query it with normal sql.I tried to implement your needs with UDF in cosmos db.

Udf code:

```
function userDefinedFunction(peopleObj){
    var returnArray = [];
    for(var key in peopleObj){
        if (peopleObj[key].first_name == "Bob"){
            var map = {};
            map[key] = peopleObj[key];
            returnArray.push(map);
        }
    }
    return returnArray;
}
```

Sql:

```
SELECT udf.test(c.data.people) as BobPeople FROM c
```

Sample data:

[image]

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Marked Jay's answer as the accepted answer as I ended up using udfs - I'll post the function I ended up using and the query for anyone looking for something a little more generic.

```
function userDefinedFunction(properties, fieldName, filedValue){
    for(var k in properties){  
        if(properties[k][fieldName] && properties[k][fieldName] == filedValue)
            return true;  
    }
    return false;
}
```

with a query of:

```
select * from c where udf.hasValue(c.data.people,"first_name","Bob")
```

Comment: I had an answer written for this, which also used a UDF, but was more generic - I commented before answering as I wanted a bit more clarity on the type of result you expected back.

Comment: sorry, once I checked back on this ticket I already had it figured out and there was an answer that was close enough to my own solution.

Comment: no problem, out if curiosity, how big is your collection potentially going to be? Also, what is your Partition Key?

Comment: not sure about the partition key, currently the collection is about 2mb worth of data and I see no degradation in the query.

Comment: it's all about the RU/s, I dont know what you have provisioned at the minute, or your estimated collection size, but as it stands your solution (and the accepted answer) would both scan every record which as you can imagine could be extremely inefficient and potentially costly if the collection grows. As for your PK, all collections need to have a PK, you either set it when the collection is created or one is created for you (I believe it just defaults to `null`)

Comment: oh yeah, this is for a 1 off query or at least a query that wouldn't be run all that often and not on the 'base' of the collection as I'm doing in this simple example.  The actual query would most likely already have the section it needs targeted and in that targeted section the JSON can only get so big.  I wasn't the one to set up the collection initially, don't know about this specific collection's PK.  Good info though :)

Comment: you can see the PK from the Settings page of the collection :) It's worth considering potentially remodelling the data to suit the query, that way you can properly index & filter the data more quickly (what you are doing at the moment is effectively that but at the cost each time you run the query).